# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when setting almost anything

Tags: swift, fatal-error, option-type

**Here is a snippet of my code**

```
switch type
        {
        case "Pupil":
            println("Processing return from \(type)")
            let results:FMResultSet? = personDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
            while(results?.next() == true)
            {
                var gender         = results?.stringForColumn("gender")
                var ethnicity      = results?.stringForColumn("ethnicity")
                var race           = results?.stringForColumn("race")

                println("Gender = \(gender!) Ethnicity = \(ethnicity!) Race = \(race!)")

                textRace.text = race!
                textEthnicity.text = ethnicity!
                textGender.text = gender!

                textRace.hidden = false
                labelRace.hidden = false
                textEthnicity.hidden = false
                labelEthnicity.hidden = false
                textGender.hidden = false
                labelGender.hidden = false
            }
```

Irrespective of what I do I get the unexpectedly found...... message.
I know there is data in the fields because the debug window displays the debug messages I expect

**Processing return from Pupil
Gender = M Ethnicity = English Race = White

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I have looked through all of the discussions on this problem and don't see an answer anywhere.

Comment: When you debug, what line is the code breaking on?

Comment: Please fix code formatting and add line this is breaking on

Comment: It is breaking on the line textRace.text = race! but if I comment that out it breaks on the next line etc

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that `results` may or may not be `nil`. You are obtaining gender, `ethnicity` and `race` from it, and force-unwrapping (`!`) them within your `print()` function call without checking. If they happened to be `nil`, it will crash. This can happen even if `results` is non-`nil`.

Do something like this:

```
if let gender = results.results?.stringForColumn("gender"){
    // you can use gender, it has a (non-nil) value...
}
else{
    // you can not use gender (not even defined as a constant)...
}
```

Comment: Also, out of curiousity... why are `race` and `ethnicity` separate variables?